# Set cookie in WordPress before page load

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, hook, setcookie

I'm attempting to set a cookie on the user's first visit to a WordPress site that can then be used within a page template.

I've tried the following in my theme's functions.php as well as trying it as a plugin, but no joy – the cookie can't be accessed in the page's initial load.

```
function set_initial_cookie() {
    // do not run function if admin (front-end only)
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    } else {
        if(!isset($_COOKIE['wp-selected_region'])) {
            $initial_region = 'Europe';
            // set cookie expiration to 7 days
            $expiration = current_time( 'timestamp' ) + ( DAY_IN_SECONDS * 7 );
            // set cookie
            setcookie( 'wp-selected_region', $initial_region, $expiration, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        }
    }
}
add_action('init','set_initial_cookie',1);
```

In my page template, for testing purposes, the cookie value will only show up once the page has been refreshed (i.e. not on initial load)

```
echo 'My cookie: '.$_COOKIE['wp-selected_region'];
```

Is this possible? There are a few past threads touching on similar issues but the answers within those vary, and any solutions that suggest this can be done don't seem to work. I've tried various different hooks, including 'init' in this example.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Correct, the cookie will be available after the page is loaded again. You could send a refresh header.